# How to blur out one of the table lists when WooCommerce Product is out of stock

Tags: html, woocommerce, inventory, elementor

I have a custom HTML table that represents every product variations in Woocommerce. I want to blur out one of the variations from the table when that product is out of stock. How can I make a condition out of it? Is there any possible ways to make this happen? I made the table using Elementor HTML attribute.
Image of the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying a CSS [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur) filter function to your appropriate column / cells, which accepts a radius that relates to how severe of a Gaussian blur is applied to the element:

```
// The radius accepts a length (e.g. number, px, em, etc.) that indicates how
// severe the blur is (smaller units => more legible)
filter: blur(radius);
```

### Example

```css
.blurry {
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<b>Normal Text:</b> This is an example
<br />
<b>Blurred Text:</b> <span class='blurry'>This is an example</span>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do but I cant get the value of the current stock of products from WooCommerce thats why I can't apply this.

Comment: I need to get the current stock status of the product on woocommerce first then put this as a result

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with WooCommerce, but I'd imagine there's some API that you could use like [this one](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) that might allow you to get the data you are looking for. Once you have that, you could use to to dynamically build a table (and apply the code above to handle blurring out items based on your needs). Basically once you can build your HTML table - you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself and for future purposes I'll leave the answer here.

- First I try to get the availability value of the product by using the code below :

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
   function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
      $var = "";
      // Change In Stock Text
      if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
          $availability['availability'] = __('In Stock', 'woocommerce');
      }
      // Change Out of Stock Text
      if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
          $availability['availability'] = __('Out of Stock', 'woocommerce');
      }
      return $availability;
  }
  ```
- Then I created a variable that will store the variation ID of the product

  ```
  if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
          $var = __($_product->get_id(), 'woocommerce');
      }
  ```
- And lastly make a condition out of it and apply the style for each row. For this example the variation ID is 2049.

```
 if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
         $availability['availability'] = __('Out of Stock', 'woocommerce');
        $var = __($_product->get_id(), 'woocommerce');
        // MINI OUT OF STOCK
        if ($var == "2049"){
             echo "<style>.product-matrix #variant-row-1{
                     filter:brightness(0.5);
                     pointer-events:none;
             }</style>";
         }
     }
```